# How to apply CSS to created pdf file in ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net, css

I have generated a pdf file using third party now I want apply my own style to the content in pdf.

Can I insert an External CSS File into a generate PDF.
I have tried many ways but all is not working.
Thanks,

Comment: PDFs and CSS have nothing to do with each-other.

Comment: This question is a little vague - You are going to have to provide more details. Also, are you saying you have created a PDF and you want to apply your stylesheet to an existing PDF file you've created, or are you saying you've got the initial creation of the PDF working and now you want to add your stylesheet to the creation process?

Comment: @SLaks, true, but you can get third party tools that take HTML (with the associated CSS) to create a PDF and I think that is probably what he's asking about. I think he wants to take some HTML, assign his own CSS to that and generate a PDF using the third-party tool.

Comment: At time of creating a pdf using third party tool Itextsharp,How can i assign my own css to dynamically generate PDF.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot style an already generated PDF with CSS. It is not made out of selectable elements and there is no way to link the CSS to the PDF.

You will have to do the styling *before* the PDF is created. It's like trying to add more sugar to an already baked cake, there is no way to do it.

Comment: Thanks for reply, I want to apply css at the time of creation of pdf.So how can i do this.

Comment: @Hitesh: That completely depends on _how_ you're creating the PDF.

Comment: @Slaks: I am using Itextsharp dll So how can apply my CSS class.